# Per server request memory budget

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocator

I would like to prevent a single query of death to my server OOMing it. Is there a way to have a memory budget for the request and throw if it uses more than allowed?

For example, is it possible to have a custom allocator and pass around unique request id as the request is processed. When an allocation is being made, use the request id to determine from which budget I am allocating?

This is a single process server, using threads inside and (and spawning additional thread when processing the request).

Comment: I think you need to give us much more contextual detail about exactly what you're using and what you're attempting.  For general info about setting process resource limits, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

Comment: @MikeRobinson This is for a single process server with threads per request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any standard solutions, but if you use Linux and if you handle requests in child processes (which is a good idea for several reasons), then you can put those children into a cgroup and set a memory limit for that cgroup.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a single process server with threads. I want to prevent the process from dying.

Comment: @gruszczy I would suggest changing the design in that case.

Comment: At this stage this is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: @gruszczy My second best idea is to replace the operator new with a custom allocation function that checks the current thread, keeps a tally and fails when limit is reached. This wouldn't prevent the threads from getting (nor would it count) the memory, from lower level API (such as `malloc` or `mmap`).

Comment: Having a custom allocator was something I was thinking about too. The only wrinkle is that the thread information is not sufficient, as we pass the execution between threads. So we would need to have some work identifier and pass that around and then have the allocator inspect that. I guess we could put that into thread locals, so whenever a thread picks work, it can update the request id for which the work is being done?

Comment: @gruszczy seems reasonable.